# Curl and Macosx 10.12

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am trying to write code in C++ to get content from a url. I have found this url: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

I tried to:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.6"
./configure --with-darwinssl
make
make install
```

But not sure what it is the new file created? What is the output of running these commands?

After unzipping the files from the zip downloaded I see a file curl.h, I guess I can use that one on my C++ program?

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**
I have found: "make install" just copies compiled files into appropriate locations.

Which are these locations?

**UPDATE 2**
Making all in lib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make

I understand now that "makefile" is the one setting where to copy files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).  It is a package manager for OS X, and has tons of packages you can install from, including curl.

Comment: Hi Pat, but how can I get the library to include it on my c++ code?

Comment: @Eduardo are you using Xcode to write your program?

Comment: I am new to C++. I am using Eclipse

Comment: @Eduardo I'm not sure where you are failing, do you have any code written?  Have you ever written a C++ program before?

Comment: Written simple stuff. I know I have to include curl.h header and that comes with the curl source code

Comment: @Eduardo okay cool.  So what you need to do is find out where the header file and the library file (should be called 'libcurl.so') is located, and add an Include Path to the directory of the header file into your Eclipse project settings.  You also need to add a Library Path to the directory containing the libcurl.so file to your Project Settings.

Comment: @Eduardo then, you need to "Link" your project to that library "libcurl.so".  I have never used Eclipse before, so you are going to have to figure out the project settings on your own.